# Jasny-Bootstrap Off Canvas and headroom.js conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I'm trying to develop a new joomla 3 template and want to use Jasny-Bootstrap Off Canvas and headroom.js
I have them working independantly but when I add them both to the template, headroom.js causes Jasny-Bootstrap Off Canvas to break.
I've isolated it to headroom.js use of    transform: translateY(0%);

Scenario, if you resize the browser of the below development site and click on the hamburger then the menu slides in and slides out - GREAT!  If you then scroll down the headroom works - Great.  However if you press the hamburger after first scrolling down then up the menu does not slide in.
Any ideas?

[development site](http://dev.webdesco.com)

Comment: How to open Off canvas on your site?

Comment: when you reduce the browser width the horizontal menu will be replaced by a 'hamburger'  click the hamburger to invoke the off canvas.

Comment: I think you have to move you offcanvas menu outside your #navigation div.

Comment: Check this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvPQNX

Comment: Thanks for that. I pretty sure have to keep the menu inside the an bar so as you can see the horizontal menu when viewing full screen. I've had both off canvas and headroom working together by just using display:block and display:none as you've done in your example. The problem occurs when you add the headroom animation

Comment: With animation: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvPQNX

Comment: Can I ask your opinion on something?  Your method on implementation required a duplicate of the navbar menu inside the navmenu. Which would be best to use, php (server side) or javascript (client side) to reproduce the menu? I can easily do it in PHP but I'm clueless in javascript.  cheers and thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not an big expert, but I think PHP will work better, especially in Joomla.